# iOS Adding Localized Accessibility text in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, accessibility

I want to add the Accessibility Label as a localization value in the story board. How do i achieve that?

Im using objective C coding and not Swift.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add the Accessibility Label as a localization value in the storyboard. How do i achieve that?

I created a blank project with a label and a button to try and reach your goal:

1. I added a french language in the `Localizations`part of the project.
2. Once validated the first step, a new file dedicated to the new language is also added. This file will contain some properties modifications on graphical objects defined by their ID.
   [image]

Directly in the storyboard, I changed the accessibility label of the `Label` element *(default is english language)* and opened the `Main.strings` file to change values as follows *('Main' is the default name of my storyboard)*:
[image]
You can find out the names of the interface builder XML properties thanks to a comparison of branches in Xcode looking at the modifications of the storyboard for instance.

The result in the Xcode Interface Builder is displayed hereunder:
[image]

... and the result for a device with french settings hereafter:
[image]

Following this rationale, you can now **add localized accessibility text in storyboard** with no lines of *{ObjC /Swift}* code.